# How to access the argument to a case statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, case

`make_api_call` is an expensive resource.

```
response = make_api_call

case response
when Net::HTTPSuccess
  response.body
else
  'not found'
end
```

Is there a way to access the "case object" so that:

```
case make_api_call
when Net::HTTPSuccess
  ???.body
```

Comment: if make_api_call is expensive (and presumably you want to avoid the cost of it) wouldn't the second example incur the same cost? I'm probably just not getting what you're asking

Comment: The idea would be to access the ___response___ from the make_api_call, instead of calling it again.

Comment: Why don't you alter `make_api_call` to return something with a more convenient interface? Say a `response.success?` method...

Comment: I don't understand. `response` already has a convenient interface that includes `#body`. What would `response.success?` return?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to get to the argument of the `case`. I didn't see anything in `Binding`. But you can assign to a local and pass it to the `case` all in one go like this:

```
case response = make_api_call
when Net::HTTPSuccess
  response.body
else
  'not found'
end
```

I don't actually recommend this. (I'd just write it as in the question.) It doesn't scope `response` to the `case` and it causes a Ruby warning (although so do a lot of not genuinely incorrect things). But people whose code standards allow or encourage assignments in conditionals might prefer it to separate assignment.

Comment: That's more succinct but less readable to me. I don't like wrapping a conditional around an assignment.

Comment: hmm. for me, It doesn't make sense, you put it out there as an option.